# How to set PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT on per-project basis

Tags: python, directory, virtualenv, project, pipenv

I want pipenv to create its virtualenv in `$PROJECTDIR/.venv` automatically for everyone who checks out the project.

So far, I see only the following options working, none of which is satisfying:

- Ask users to set PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 globally, forcing my project preferences on each of their other projects.
- Ask users to always invoke pipenv via "`PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv`" when inside my project, which begs for trouble if they run a `pipenv` command and forget to set `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT`.
- Ask users to install a third-party tool `direnv` and provide an `.envrc` file, adding yet another non-obvious build dependency.

I tried the following approaches:

- Add an PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT-like option to Pipfile, but I couldn't find any such Pipfile option.
- Put "`PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1`" into `$PROJECTDIR/.env`, but that is only evaluated inside the sub shell of `pipenv shell/run`, and is ignored by `pipenv` itself.

So, how do I set PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT on per-project basis?

Comment: Out of curiosity, when would it be important to define *where* a virtual environment is located from the perspective of the project?

Comment: @np8 The target audience are people who want to try and build the tool, but are not so much into the intracities of Python build environments. One important expectation is that after trying stuff, deleting the project directory should be enough to remove the tool, without any leftovers in the rest of their system, especially without leftovers like virtual envs consuming lots of disk space. This is only possible if the virtual env is inside the project directory.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To answer this question myself, this is indeed possible!

**Short story:**

Just create an empty .venv directory yourself. Pipenv will pick this up automaticaly.

**Long story:**

Note that there are many issues in the pipenv issue tracker that give the wrong impression that the pipenv developers don't want to provide this feature. However, those issues simply describe additional ways to achieve this goal, and those additional ways were declined.

But within that mess, there was one comment that was actually helpful:

- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2197#issuecomment-446601760

> techalchemy commented on Dec 12, 2018
>
> Things you can do:
>
> 1. Simply create the .venv yourself. Pipenv will use it.
> 2. Use a tool like direnv to activate this setting per directory
> 3. Set the envvar globally
> 4. Create a file in the project root called .venv whose contents are only the path to the root directory of a virtualenv
>
> For points 1 and 4, pipenv will pick this up automatically

**Note:** If you want to use the `pipenv` shipped with current Debian/Stable (Buster), point 4 won't work, as this feature was introduced in a later `pipenv` version. However, point 1 works perfectly well. For Python 3, this means:

```
python3 -m virtualenv -p python3 .venv
pipenv install ...  # resp. pipenv sync
```

Comment: Simply having an empty `.venv` folder works too! great solution!

Comment: Awesome. you save me a lot of time

Comment: How do I checkin an empty `.venv` for our project?

Comment: @Alper Don't! The contents of the .venv directory are not meant to be committed into version control anyways. Instead, let your build scripts create it. E.g. if you have a Makefile, it might contain a target that executes "python3 -m virtualenv -p python3 .venv" ... just prepent a command like "mkdir -p .venv" before that.

Comment: I don't mean checking in the contents but you would need to have a the folder to be there for python to pick it up, or?

Comment: If you prepend "mkdir -p" before the virtualenv command (as described in my previous comment), you don't need to do this. In my projects, I strongly prefer that over adding dummy directories into my repository.